# Where is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client 12.0.30723.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 Premium Update 4, with TFS 2013 Update 3. 
i'm trying to locate the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client that is version 12.0.30723 that matches TFS 2013 update 3, but no where can i find it.

i've looked on my machine at 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

but that dll isn't even listed.

i'm also looking for : 
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll

but nothing

when i dig around for them on the tfs server i don't find them either..
i do find:  (i found those also on dev machine):
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.dll
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll
    etc...

but not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to install Visual Studio 2013 to have these assemblies. And all these assemblies you listed above can be found in the path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0`

Additionally, 12.0.30723 is version for TFS2013 with Update 3. For VS 2013 Premium Update 4, the version is 12.0.21005.1. And you can use 12.0.21005.1 version dll to connect to TFS2013 with Update 3.

Comment: tx much for the info.. had a hard time locating the right files for some reason.